# Polymer controlling number of DOM nodes on a page

Tags: polymer-1.0

> On youtube polymer channel there is a talk about performance. One of
>   key concepts they say is to have less Nodes as possible when
>   application starts, loading others (Nodes) in async mode.

With this concept after all, if I have a huge application, I will end up with everything loaded and many many nodes on page.

One of the key element in polymer is `iron-pages`. It can communicate with `app-route` and other app elements. It works by hiding inactive pages (DOM Nodes) with `display:none` depending on a `state` (most often URL).

So here is the picture:

I have 20 different pages. After everything loaded I have all this pages in my `document` with `display:none` and one page that is active.

Questions:

1) Is that true that polymer concept is to have all nodes (pages) hidden rather than dynamically rendering/removing depending on a state?

2) If yes, does not that affect the browser performance comparing to dynamically rendering/removing like in Meteor?

3) What should I do with all the listeners/observers on pages that are inactive (display:none)? Should they be stopped when webcomponent becomes invisible?

---

I see that only `dom-repeat` `dom-if` and `iron-list` removes and adds content dynamically. All other components on the page, including forms, views stay on page forever.

Answer (score 0):

1) definitely wrong
See for example https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route

2) it does, therefore this should be avoided

3) not applicable ;-)

Also https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list is built to only render what is visible for the exact same purpose.

Comment: I looked at example. It has two application states:  `results listing` and `video view`. Both components are rendered in the document  and managed with iron-pages. Both components exist on the page whatever the application state is. Only difference is that one is hidden depending on what the app state is. That's what I was talking about.

Comment: `Also https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list is built to only render what is visible for the exact same purpose.` what do you mean render? it renders everything, but hides what is not needed. It does not remove or add anything on page.

Comment: If you scroll the list (with a lots of items) up and down, items that are scrolled outside of the visible area are actually removed from the DOM and re-added when they become visible again (virtual scrolling)

Comment: My bad, I was thinking you are talking about iron-pages. Yes, iron-list, dom-repeat, dom-if are making dynamic renders, but I see all other components should stay on page forever.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all other components". I'm sure the router removes them if you route away. I didn't have a closer look but I wrote a router for Polymer myself and I removed the elements when they were not active on the current route.

Comment: By all other components I mean all the forms, all the views you have in your application. The thing is that `app-route` does not remove anything. It just matches url and provides binding that you can use with `iron-pages` for example. Try their shop demo. https://shop.polymer-project.org
Maybe some third party routers do this, but not official solution. That's why I'm interested in that

Comment: It's not complicated. Adding/removing Polymer elements is the same as adding/removing a `<div>`.

Comment: I know I know, just interested if it's not official solution of doing routing. (Shop app is an example)

Comment: I didn't investigate closer. I'm currently working on other stuff than Polymer.